# Dynamically add correct class to constructor depending on callee

Tags: php, constructor, repository, code-reuse

I have thees repository classes which implement the same contracts and pattern, so basically I have a bunch of theese:

```
class EmployeeRepository {
    private $transformer; //instance of EmployeeTransformer
    public function find() {
        return new ReturnObject($this->transformer, $employee);
    }
}

class CustomerRepository {
    private $transformer; //instance of CustomerTransformer
    public function find() {
        return new ReturnObject($this->transformer, $customer);
    }
}
```

as you can see they all return a ReturnObject which basically takes the transformer object and the entity object as constructor parameters.  The transformer is used for the ReturnObject to determine the output format for the controller classes.

```
class ReturnObject {
      private $transformer;
      private $response;

      function __construct($transformer, $entity) {
          $this->transformer = $transformer;
          $this->entity = $entity;
          $this->response = new ApiResponse();
      }

      public function apiResponse() {
          return $this->response->array($this->transformer, $entity);
      }
}
```

My question is regarding the constructor parameter for the transformer. Is there a way for the repositorys to be able to transfer the correct transformer class to the ReturnObject without having to send it as a constructor parameter? Maybe with a factory pattern design?
There are 2 reasons I want to remove the argument from the constructor:

1. The constructor already has a lot of arguments. (I have removed them from my examples above, to make the code simpler to understand, but in reality there are 6 parameters already to the constructor except for the transformer)
2. I have a lot of repositories with a lot of functions, and it would be neat to not having to send the transformer in all the returns to reduce code and potentially errors

Comment: Very difficult to help without seeing the bigger picture. Also, this question looks to vague for SO. Perhaps you can flesh this out with more details and ask it on CodeReview instead. As a note, i would very much expect a customer repository to return a customer, not a weirdly named `ReturnObject`. The whole point of a repository is to decouple your domain objects from their persistence.

Comment: Sounds like the builder pattern might improve the quality of your code https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder

Comment: @Steve The repository must return domain objects to different controllers that are expecting different format. For example I have a web controller that expects the domain object as itselft, and I also have an api controller who expects the same object as json data. Therefor the returnhelper will handle the correct format to the correct controller

Comment: @Steve This would likely not be a good fit for Code Review as phrased, as it is asking if the code can be written to do something differently.

Comment: @Steve I'd venture as far to say that this question would probably be closed as-is on Code Review, simply because we don't accept questions that are asking us to write code and/or contain incomplete code. If the code *is* complete, and the OP simply requests a review, then it is on-topic.

Comment: soo.... @Steve straight up front. You're mostly wrong. This question isn't a good fit for Code Review as is, because ad 1) it's a condensed example and ad 2) it's asking or a specific rewrite. This question is at least acceptable for Stack Overflow because it has a condensed example and a specific question. It might be considered "Primarily Opinion Based" but I think this question is focused enough to stay open as is.

Comment: @Vogel612 Ok, well i was trying to convey that this could be made into a decent CR question with some changes, but I dont have much experience on CR anyway, i am just starting to use it, because the questions are so much more in depth, and thus fun to answer. Perhaps this question has no place on any SE site, which would be a shame because its clearly more thought out that a lot of the dross that gets answered every few seconds on SO, especially in the [php] tag